# Invalid syntax for % operator in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a newbie to Python, and I have been using Python 2.7 for learning the language. But my python returns invalid syntax when i use the % operator for string formatting.

Why is returning such error, and what is the solution?

The code:

```
# Filename: print_tuple.py

age = 22
name = 'Deepak'

print '%s is %d years old' % (name, age)
print 'Why is %s?' % name
```

Comment: Can you post some example code where you've tried to use `%`?

Comment: Yes, please post the code where you use it, and just in case it looks right, post stack-trace

Comment: # Filename: print_tuple.py
age = 22
name = 'Deepak'
print '%s is %d years old' % (name, age)
print 'Why is %s?' % name

Comment: @DeepakEshwar -- Please edit your question, including the full traceback

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code, but it works just fine for me. Can you share the full traceback from your exception? Please edit it into the question, since it will be spread over several lines.

Comment: @Marius # Filename: print_tuple.py
age = 22
name = 'Deepak'
print '%s is %d years old' % (name, age)
print 'Why is %s?' % name

Comment: Sounds like you're executing the script as something else. Try running it with `python print_tuble.py` instead of just the filename.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the given code. It works smoothly in Python. If you saved it as "code.py" try: python code.py should be fine.

Comment: @root -- Thanks for the reply, but as i said I am new and not quite sure about the traceback logging in python, can you tell me the procedure so that, I will add the full traceback to the question.

Comment: @Blckknght -- Thanks for the reply, but as i said I am new and not quite sure about the traceback logging in python, can you tell me the procedure so that, I will add the full traceback to the question.

Comment: @DeepakEshwar: The traceback is what you get when an exception stops the interpreter from running your program. It should output some text, starting with `Traceback (most recent call last):` and going on for several lines.

Comment: @kichik I tried the prog with python in cmd and also in the python shell IDLE, but both are returning the same error. Ivalid syntax %

Comment: @Blckknght oki, how do i get the traceback for the above program while i am running with cmd?

Comment: re traceback: You say 'my python returns invalid syntax' but you did not give that output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method, this will ellininates part of misunderstandings with %. For example:

```
myStr = '{0} int and {1} string and {2} list...'
mystr.format(10, 'string value', range(10)
```

In case you still need to work with % notation than please read carefully the following link:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Think you simply use incorrect conversion.

As per your sample:

```
def print_data(age, name):
    print '{0} is {1} years old'.format(name, age) 
    print 'Who is {0}?'.format(name)

print_data(22, 'Depak')
```

Comment: # Filename: print_tuple.py
age = 22
name = 'Deepak'
print '%s is %d years old' % (name, age)
print 'Who is %s?' % name

Comment: The above is the program, but when I ran it using the cmd, it is returning as % is an invalid syntax.

Comment: Oki, but is the format method standard to use the tuple using the print and the print statement?

Comment: @DeepakEshwar format is new suggested way of string formatting: "This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code." from python tutorial

Comment: @Aristom Rudzenka Yea, i tried the updated sample, its running perfectly.